# Upload file to server(Unity)

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine, web, upload

So I have looked at the unity document and some tutorials on youtube, I managed to create a localhost server and put some data on the server. Right now I can download the file that I have uploaded.

My problem is how to upload to the Webserver, when I upload the string I want to upload, the debug.log show success. However, when I opened the file on the server, the string I uploaded didn't write into the 123.txt file.

What I'm trying to do here is upload a string/JSON file to the server and download it, I am able to download it but not upload it. Some tutorials online show some PHP scripts, is it possible that I upload a string to the server and automatically turn it into a txt file and stored?

I try to set the path to http://localhost/Project/, which I want to do is to store the string or JSON file to the Project file. However, it results in Http404Notfound. If I do http://localhost/Project/123.txt, it is a success for upload. But the data I uploaded didn't get written into the 123txt file.

What should I do from here?

Upload_Code

```
IEnumerator Upload()
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("myField", "myData");
    byte[] myData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is some test data");

    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Put("http://localhost/Project/123.txt", myData))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        { 
            ServerResult.text = www.downloadHandler.text;
            Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm able to download a picture that I manually drag and drop to the server.

Download_From_Server

```
private void GetTexture(string url, Action<string> OnError, Action<Texture2D> OnSuccess)
       
        {
            StartCoroutine(GetServerTexture(url,OnError,OnSuccess));
        } 
        private IEnumerator GetServerTexture(string url, Action<string> OnError, Action<Texture2D> OnSuccess)
        {
            using (UnityWebRequest unityWebRequest = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(url))
            {
                yield return unityWebRequest.SendWebRequest();
                if (unityWebRequest.isNetworkError || unityWebRequest.isHttpError)
                {
                    OnError(unityWebRequest.error);
                }
                else
                {
                    DownloadHandlerTexture downloadHandlerTexture = unityWebRequest.downloadHandler as DownloadHandlerTexture;
                    OnSuccess(downloadHandlerTexture.texture);
                    //Debug.Log("Received: " + unityWebRequest.downloadHandler.text);
                    //ServerResult.text = unityWebRequest.downloadHandler.text;
    
                }
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: You have to have a page that receives the data and stores it.

Comment: _"is it possible that I upload a string to the server and automatically turn it into a txt file and stored?"_ - many things are _possible_, but they don't magically happen by themselves. Making a PUT request and configuring the server to allow creation of a file based on that would be one option. But simply placing a script there that receives the data and processes it the way you want, is probably the more common way.